# Laravel 4 Route Level Access

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, access-levels

I need to Add Level access to my website
and i usually code my route like :

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'home-view',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@viewHome'
));

/* Authenticated Group */
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'admin-view',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@viewAdmin'
    ));
}
/* Unauthenticated Group */
Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function(){
    Route::get('/signin', array(
        'as' => 'user-signin-get',
        'uses' => 'UserController@getSignIn'
    ));
}
```

i need to add level access as "user" or "admin". how i can do that filter route? as simple as possiple or what do you recommend?

Comment: I’d suggest you read up on route filters in the Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many filters to a single route as you like.  Consider this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|hasAdminLevel'), function(){
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'admin-view',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@viewAdmin'
    ));
});
```

This will apply both the `auth` as well as the `hasAdminLevel` filter to your `admin-view` route.  The `hasAdminLevel` route is a [custom filter](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) that you will need to define.

**Update**

`hasAdminLevel` is a custom filter, and can be defined like this:

```
Route::filter('hasAdminLevel', function() {
    if(Auth::user()->level != 'admin') {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Where you place this is a little up to you, but a good place would be in the aptly named `app/filters.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that u have a **users** (id, username, etc), **roles**(id, name, etc), and **user_role**(user_id, role_id, etc) tables and the relationships properly setup in your models.

So you can create a new function in ur User Model to check if a user have a role.

```
public function hasRole($name) {
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        if ($role->name == $name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can create a filter for that:

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $role){
if( Auth::guest() or !Auth::user()->hasRole($role) ) {
    return Redirect::guest('/'); // whatever you want
}
```

});

And finally just apply the filter to your routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'role:the_role_name_you_want'], function(){
  // Your Routes here
});
```